# Is the statement "All the threads that run on a given SM may cooperate" true or false?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

In the Quiz: Thread and Blocks of "Intro to Parallel Programming" on Udacity, it asks whether the statement "All the threads that run on a given SM **may** cooperate to solve a problem" is true or false. The answer is false however I think it should be true because:

- It use "may" rather than "must".
- Some paper are talking about inter-block GPU communication.

Do I have any misunderstanding of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true in all cases.

In the typical CUDA sense of cooperating threads, cooperating threads must belong to the same block (so as to be able to use cooperative mechanisms like `__syncthreads()` and `__shared__` memory).

An SM, however, can contain multiple blocks executing simultaneously.

Threads from separate blocks, even if resident on the same SM, cannot cooperate, in the typical CUDA sense of the words "cooperating threads".

Comment: The paper http://synergy.cs.vt.edu/pubs/papers/xiao-ipdps2010-gpusync.pdf proposed inter-block GPU communication. It seems under some cases "All the threads that run on a given SM may cooperate to solve a problem", does it?

Comment: I have defined what I mean by cooperating threads. I think it is a commonly used definition for CUDA threads. According to my definition, I believe my answer is correct, and the paper you've cited does not allow threads from separate blocks to communicate e.g. via `__shared__` memory, so I don't think your paper has any relevance for the definition I have given. All threads can communicate with each other via global memory (even without your paper), so an alternate definition may fit your viewpoint. I don't agree it is correct for a commonly accepted definition of "cooperating threads" in CUDA

Answer (score -1):

The CUDA official material[1] mentioned what Robert Crovella said in page 8:

- Threads in different blocks cannot cooperate.

[1] https://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/download/Getting_Started_w_CUDA_Training_NVISION08.pdf